# Save PySpark log to text file

Tags: logging, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark to run some simulations with different datasets and I'd like to save all the console output (INFOS, WARNS, etc...) to a text file in an on-the-fly fashion, that is by declaring inside the code the text file that will contain the log output. The code will simply run some operations on an input dataset and I'm planning to run the code using `spark-sumbit`.

This will allow me to save separate logs for separate simulations, the idea behind it is to match the log filename with the input dataset name.

Is that possible without changing `confs` and other Spark files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using yarn-cluster you could get the loggings from,

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```

If its local or client you could do,

```
spark-submit myapp.py 2> mylogfile
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a yarn cluster, I've got Spark Context on `local[*]`. Thus I'm using all the cores in my machine as a cluster. The `>` is nice anyways, although it allows me only to catch Python tracebacks

Comment: You could also `2>` and `&>` for getting loggings in stderr and stdout

Comment: Thank you very much indeed WoodChopper. Nice catch. Although (for the sake of completeness) I'd extend your hint to `/ 2>&1 | tee myLog.log`. In this manner I do have both the log on console and file. Indeed both `2>` and `&>` suppress the output on Terminal.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see how can i  achieve the same from inside my PySpark code. It is still a bit "ugly" to redirect stderr to stdout in your spark-submit jobs